# angular-cli : How to reference an element using jQuery

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

The problem - I have another instance of **[slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)** and things got messy.

How can I set a variable for my private `el` variable inside my constructor here:

**e.g. - How can I use a direct reference to an element using jquery, instead of searching trough the whole tree like I am doing here?**

`jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).variable.slick({..`

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, HostListener, Input, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowRefService } from 'app/core/window-ref.provider';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-preview',
    templateUrl: 'app-preview.component.html'
})

export class AppPreviewComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slick({
            infinite: false,
            arrows: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            centerMode: true,
            dots: false,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            cssEase: 'ease-in-out'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to found a resolution. In its simplest form.

What it was:

```
jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slick({
    ...
});
```

What I needed this to be (and it works):

```
jQuery('app-preview').slick({
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your `jQuery.slick()` plugin is, but on the Angular2 part:

You may want to consider putting this in the `ngAfterViewInit()` method (don't forget to add it to the `implements` part), as this is fired in the lifecycle where the HTML has been loaded.

It might be interesting to lookup the `ViewChild()` part of Angular2. It looks kinda like this:

`ViewChild('some-id') variableName: ElementRef`

and in your HTML:

`<blabla #some-id></blabla>`

You will then have access in your controller to `this.variableName` which you string other functions, like jQuery plugins to.

Comment: Thank You for this Bjorn, but I was simply referring to the simplest form of jQuery object reference. I think I found my way around this.